# Why the state of port is not listen while I've created a UDP monitor on this port using Netty?

Tags: java, udp, netty

this's the code to create a channel:

```
 public class StunServer {

    private StunServer(){
        boolean win = GeneralUtil.windows();
        if(win){
            System.out.println("windows");
            this.group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        }else{
            System.out.println("linux");
            this.group = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
        }
        this.bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group).channel(win?NioDatagramChannel.class:EpollDatagramChannel.class)
//                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST,true)
                .handler(new ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
                        channel.pipeline()
                                .addLast(new StunUdpMsgDecoder())
                                .addLast(new StunUdpMsgEncoder())
                                .addLast(new StunUdpMsgHandler());
                    }
                });
    }

    private static StunServer instance = new StunServer();

    public static StunServer getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    private final Bootstrap bootstrap;
    private final EventLoopGroup group;


    public Channel getChannel(int port){
        System.out.println("bind port："+port);
        ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(port).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture channelFuture) throws Exception {
                if(!channelFuture.isSuccess()){
                    channelFuture.cause().printStackTrace();
                    channelFuture.channel().close();
                }
            }
        }).syncUninterruptibly();
        return channelFuture.channel();
    }

    public void stop(){
        group.shutdownGracefully().syncUninterruptibly();
    }
}
```

and this's the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        StunServer server = StunServer.getInstance();
        try {
            Channel channel = server.getChannel(VarEnums.server1.getPort());
            channel.closeFuture().sync();
        }catch(Exception  e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            server.stop();
        }
    }
```

quite simple,I'm pretty sure that the message was sent successfully.but the decoder was not excuted.
and found that the port was not listened.

[netstat -nap | grep java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiQyF.png)

as you see.and it should be like this?I guess.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojQGG.png)

anyway dudes help me,thanks.